# UI assign item to multiple targets

Tags: usability, gui-design, filter, pagination, scalability

I need something really simple to be able to assign plan to multiple employees.

First I was thinking about a list and u could just select the employees you want, but this would get really clunky with lets say 10+ employees.

So this got me thinking I would introduce some kind of quick search in the top for employee filtering, but I still dont like this solution at all

[image]

The formating and functionality is not completed but you get the idea.. I feel like this takes so much space... I need some kind of solution that is scalable 1-30 employees lets say. I could add also pagination for the list of the employees but that doesnt solve the root of the problem and I dont think that this is readable for the user at all anyway.

Comment: Outlook (and other softwares) do this and use what appears to be a widely recognised pattern: entering text into a field generates a shortlist based on the input which is refined by further typing. - Is there any reason you can't use this pattern for your task? Adding these reasons to your question may help you get better answers.

Comment: Thats ok for a small group size of 10ppl max I would say, but imagine scenario with 20 employees and you would like to assign the plan to 15 of them. That would require you to atleast start typing 15names? Unfortunately there is no way currently to filter employees into some kind of teams so..

Comment: Then that's what you need - some way of setting and managing groups - The product you're building simply won't scale if you don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have solved this in a way Andrew Martin suggested. I have used multiple select typehead.

[image]

Until there is a proper way to filter people into organizing units this is sufficient solution.